# AS3 - Encrypted local storage

Tags: actionscript-3, security, air

I need to store a password locally from a Flash based app that runs within a browser. Is there an Flash equivalent to Air's [encrypted local storage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html)? (I'm publishing for Flash Player 10)

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd strongly advise against this, because the only way you can do this is by using Flash's shared objects, which are accessible to any flash application. Someone could simply create a flash wrapper to your SWF application and have people visit through their wrapper and then collect sensitive information (the password) with great ease. I'm posting this an answer because if you ever want anyone to feel remotely secure while using your application, this is the only answer.

On another note, you could simply write an AIR app and then when people visit your apps website, they can either have their AIR app launched from your web page or be prompted to install it if they do not already have it. Check out these links for more NFO on that:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html#1035834
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fcb.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e15

Comment: Also write this down as a general rule to follow: NOTHING you write in actionscript 3 and compile is secure. Ever. I once wrote my own encryption extension to AIR because of this. Actionscript 3 based apps are extremely easy to reverse engineer. So never trust that any algorithm, any string literals (example, statically storing a secure application ID or anything secure in text inside your code) will ever be safe. Ever.